# All possible argument specifications for a function in R

Tags: r, function, loops, combinatorics

I have a function with the following form:

```
model <- Create(parameter1 = list(model = "a" , "b"),
                parameter2 = list(distribution = "x" , "y"))
```

I want to create all possible specifications os this 'model' using the function above.

The possible values for `parameter1` and `parameter2` are:

```
parameter1: "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"
```

and

```
parameter2: "x", "y", "z", "w", "t", "v"
```

I've tried to use the `for` loop, but it didn't work so far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are the model, distribution takes two values at a time

Comment: @akrun Yes, always two values at a time. Can be repeated values.

Comment: library(tidyr)
parameter1 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
parameter2<- c("x", "y", "z", "w", "t", "v")
crossing(parameter1, parameter2)

does this help get you started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `combn` to create paired combinations of each 'parameter',

```
 d1 <- expand.grid(parameter1, parameter1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

 d2 <- expand.grid(parameter2, parameter2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
 names(d2) <- c("Var3", "Var4")
```

then with `expand.grid` or `crossing`, expand both datasets created

```
library(tidyr)
parameter_dat <- crossing(d1, d2)
str(parameter_dat)
tibble [900 × 4] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Var1: chr [1:900] "a" "a" "a" "a" ...
 $ Var2: chr [1:900] "a" "a" "a" "a" ...
 $ Var3: chr [1:900] "t" "t" "t" "t" ...
 $ Var4: chr [1:900] "t" "v" "w" "x" ...
```

Loop over the rows of the dataset and apply the function

```
library(purrr)
pmap(parameter_dat, ~ Create(parameter1 = list(model = c(..1, ..2)),
                parameter2 = list(distribution = c(..3, ..4))))
```

#### data

```
parameter1 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
parameter2 <- c("x", "y", "z", "w", "t", "v")
```

Comment: the only problem with that solution is that it ignores the case of repeated values. For instance we can have:  model <- Create(parameter1 = list(model = "a" , "a"),
                                                   parameter2 = list(distribution = "x" , "a"))

Comment: @MiguelMoreira I think you haven't executed the line above `library(tidyr);
parameter_dat <- crossing(d1, d2)`

Comment: @MiguelMoreira if you do that, you will a dimension of `dim(parameter_dat)
[1] 900   4`

Comment: Thanks!! Worked really well, just had to convert from factors to characters in parameter_dat.

Comment: I used the following to convert to characters : parameter_dat <- data.frame(lapply(parameter_dat, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE). But I think either way works

Comment: @MiguelMoreira you don't need those because `expand.grid` can return character columns, by itself if use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` (by default it returns TRUE) i.e. we don't need an additional code when we can fix at the root cause